# After installing jupyter themes, notebooks and docker container no longer working

Tags: python, docker, themes, jupyter-notebook, containers

I am running jupyter notebooks through a docker container. I have files, notebooks, etc within the container. I decide in class one day to attempt and install the jupyterthemes package because who doesn't like more colors. I opened a new ipynb and followed instructions per this site: https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes

But it was basically just this:

```
!pip install jupyterthemes

!jt -t chesterish
```

The theme does not immediately appear and the directions suggest restarting the notebook or refreshing the browser. This is where the problems start, after trying to refresh or close and restart the notebook, it no longer works and just displays a large "500 : Internal Server Error" on the page. After trying to restart the home page of my notebook (this is locally hosted through docker and run on chrome btw), the jupyter window in chrome displays nothing at all.

Here I go back to terminal and docker and shut down the container. Then I try to restart the same container hoping it will work now. I try to start it as I usually would `docker start -ai container_name` but it is not successful. It displays these errors everytime

```
Executing the command: jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", 
line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'allow_remote_access'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 869, in _default_allow_remote
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(self.ip)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: '' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1629, in initialize
self.init_webapp()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1379, in init_webapp
self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 158, in __init__
default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 251, in init_settings
allow_remote_access=jupyter_app.allow_remote_access,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 872, in _default_allow_remote
for info in socket.getaddrinfo(self.ip, self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

So I can no longer access the entire docker container and my files and notebooks within. So I have two questions then:

Can I somehow restore my docker container or at least retrieve the materials within?

and

Why did this error occur during theme installation and how could I go about doing this without breaking my jupyter server or docker container? I have built new containers and attempted again with exactly the same results.

Any advice about how to get files from a not-running docker container, or about compatibility issues between docker, jupyter and the theme package and how to solve them would be much appreciated. For the time being I can work from a new container and keep up with schoolwork, but in the future would be nice to get back my stuff from that container and learn how to successfully change my theme if I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have an answer to half the question, we found a way to copy and export all the files from my broken, not-running docker container. The files kind of 'invisible' when the container isnt running so it took some trickery to find where they are located and what path to use to call them from terminal.

I'm running docker on a macbook and the location of all the files in a new container we made were container:./home/jovyan/.

Also made a folder called 'Dump' on my normal user desktop to transfer container contents to. After messing around with new 'fake' containers we found a successful way to pull files from a not-running one. I used

```
docker cp container_name:./home/jovyan/. ./Dump
```

Where container name is obviously your container and Dump is where you want the files to go. /jovyan/ was the largest one I could call and took everything I had out of the container, but if you knew more folder and filenames you could specify farther and extract specific things.

This is probably pretty simple for most experienced programmers, but as a newbie the hard part was finding where docker stored my container files and what path to use. /home/jovyan/. worked on my mac but could be different for you. If you have a broken container just make a new test one with a recognizable file in it and mess around until you figure out how to pull it out. Opening a new terminal window within the test jupyter notebook helped me find what docker was labeling my pathways.

Still wondering how to actually install those themes though.... dont think itll work work docker and jupyter, probably just too much incompatibility already.

Answer (score 0):

If you stil have the issue, this is what fixed it for me:

1. In docker terminal, make sure you are using bash; so that the prompt starts with "(base)". I just typed `bash` and then the prompt looked good.
2. `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterthemes` (or pip if you're not using anaconda)
3. `conda update jupyterthemes` (it found some updates of other packages, apparently necessary)
4. `jt -t monokai -f fira -fs 10 -nf ptsans -nfs 11 -N -kl -cursw 2 -cursc r -cellw 95% -T` (Or another setting; this was copied from Ashraf Khan on Kaggle).
5. Hard refresh page (chrome on windows: ctrl-F5

I think step 3 was key here, but not sure. However it works now.